# sqlite3 in c++ not acknowledging my primary key

Tags: c++, database, sqlite

I am currently building a project of a database in sqlite3.
I've already made a function that inserts the table

```
t_users(username TEXT primarykey not null, password TEXT not null, email TEXT not null)
```

a new row.
the problem is the function doesn't acknowledge my primary key, and it lets me add two rows with the same username.
this is my main:

```
#include "Database.h"
int main()
{
    DataBase db;
    bool answer = db.addNewUser("user4", "1234", "user4@gmail.com");
    return 0;
}
```

and this is my addNewUser functions:

```
bool DataBase::addNewUser(string username, string password, string email)
{
    //not a really relevant part:
    username.insert(0, "'");
    username += "'";
    password.insert(0, "'");
    password += "'";
    email.insert(0, "'"); 
    email += "'";

    //this is probably the relevant part:
    char* zErrMsg;
    int rv;
    rv = sqlite3_exec(_db, ("INSERT INTO t_users(username, password, email)
    VALUES(" + username + ',' + password + ',' + email + ");").c_str(), NULL, 0, &zErrMsg);
    if (rv != SQLITE3_OK) //checking for errors that might have occured
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The blatant SQL injection vulnerability not withstanding, you say you're adding *two* rows? I only see one.

Comment: Do you create the table using `primarykey` or `primary key`? One of them is incorrect.

Comment: acutally i received the table for my project, i didnt create her.

Comment: i did .schema t_users to see what they did on the columns

Answer (score 1):

That table does not have a primary key.

The first column has the name `username` and the type `TEXT primarykey`.

To get a primary key, spell it correctly as `PRIMARY KEY`.